# How to access resource editor file to Netbeans

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwjgl

How to access resource editor file to Netbeans?/How resource editor files are imported and opened in Netbeans?Detailed description.

Answer (score 2):

Ok for open the .res file from code, you need to use this lines:

```
try{
    Resources.open("/myResFile.res");
catch(IOException ioe){
    //manage the exception
}
```

The path for your .res file will be different, in my example is like it would be in the src folder.

Comment: Fixed a minor typo in the source

Comment: thanks,but my question is ..how are the files from resourse editor imported in netbeans and excecuted?

Comment: You need to put your res file into your project and later you can open it with these orders. If you want to execute the res for using the navigation etc etc...you need to generate the project from the Resource editor

Comment: So, which storage system (File System, Storage, SQLite) should I be using given a scenario that I wanted to store a private key for encryption and decryption purpose. As the key will only be written once (private key initialization)...

Comment: make a new question and notify me